# Fixing Puzzle Game

Tags: puzzle

I'm new to C++ and programming in general, and this is my first 'project'. I'm sorry if this is not an applicable question, tell me and I will delete it right away.

I want to build a puzzle game, but instead of sliding tiles, the user swaps the number adjacent to '0', where '0' is the blank tile.

This is the code I've so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int grid[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0};

void shuffle()
{
    random_shuffle(&grid[0],&grid[9]);
}
void print_puzzle()
{
    shuffle();
    int a=grid[0];
    int b=grid[1];
    int c=grid[2];
    int d=grid[3];
    int e=grid[4];
    int f=grid[5];
    int g=grid[6];
    int h=grid[7];
    int i=grid[8];

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<a<<"  "<<b<<"  "<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<d<<"  "<<e<<"  "<<f<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<g<<"  "<<h<<"  "<<i<<endl;
}

bool check()
{
    if (grid[0]==1&&grid[1]==2&&grid[2]==3&&grid[3]==4&&grid[4]==5&&grid[6]==7&&grid[7]==8&&grid[8]==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
else
   {
        return false;
   }

}


void swap_puzzle()
{
    print_puzzle();

    int temp=0;

    cout<<"Enter the number adjacent to '0' that you want to be swapped with '0'."<<endl;
    cin>> temp;

    while(check==false)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            if(grid[i]==temp)
            {
                int pos_num=i;

                for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
                {

                    if(grid[j]==0)
                    {
                        int pos_0=j;
                        swap(grid[pos_num], grid[pos_0]);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        print_puzzle();
    }

}
int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout<<"The Rules:"<<endl;
    cout<<"There will be a shuffled 3x3 grid with numbers from 1-8, with one blank space denoted by '0'. You can swap '0' only with adjacent numbers. The goal of this game is to rearrange the numbers in the grid in ascending order."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The Shuffled Grid: "<<endl;
    swap_puzzle();
    return 0;
}
```

After swapping the number that the enter user with '0', the grid just shuffles instead of swapping them as I intended. I tried fixing this problem by breaking the code into smaller functions, but that didn't help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

- At the end of your `swap_puzzle()` function, inside the while loop, you call `print_puzzle()`. `print_puzzle` calls `shuffle()`. That's why everything is shuffled instead of having just a swap operation. To fix this you must decouple these 2 functions: printing is one thing, shuffling is another one. Neither of these should trigger the other. Or MAYBE you could have the shuffle function that calls the print one at the end, to show the new status; but a "print" function should never do anything other than printing.
- Then, in your `check()` function you have forgotten `grid[5]==6`. Actually this might not be important, because if all the others are at the right place, then grid[5] should automatically be right. Anyway, for what it costs, I would definitely add it.
- Then, your `swap_puzzle()` has a problem where you call swap and then you break. You have 2 nested for loops, and you must break from both. Right now, you are breaking from the inner one (the one that uses `j`), which means that then the program will resume at the next iteration of `i`. It is possible, then, that the swap conditions are met again, as a result of the previous swap. So the user wants to make one move, and he ends up with 2. To be precise, the second one will revert the first one, and of course this is not wanted. To solve this you could add a bool variable called `swapped` and set it to false at the beginning of the while loop; when you reach the break, before breaking you set it to true. Then, immediately after the end of the inner loop, you check the value of `swapped`: if it is true you have to break again.
- As your program is structured right now, you display `cout` and read the input with `cin` only once. You must put both functions inside the while loop, so that they are run every time, for every move.

Comment: How do I decouple the print_puzzle( ) and shuffle( ) functions, while still shuffling the grid. Because, if it doesn't read shuffle( ), the grid won't be randomized. What am I missing here?

Comment: You just have to remove the call to `shuffle();` from `print_puzzle`, so that print_puzzle will only do what its name suggests: it will _print_. Then, you will have to call `shuffle();` separetely. When do you want to shuffle the board? Only once, at the beginning. So you could e.g. put it at the beginning of swap_puzzle(), just before the line that calls `print_puzzle();`. By doing this you would shuffle the puzzle only once, which is what you want. Alternatively you could call `shuffle();` inside your `main` function, before you call `swap_puzzle();`. Anyway you have to call it only once!

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `print_puzzle` function you have this line

```
shuffle();
```

That mean every time you go to print your puzzle, it shuffles it. You don't want that.

Also this line:

```
while(check==false)
```

should be

```
while(check()==false)
```

`check` by itself is the pointer to the function, not a call to the function.

You also want to move the request for a new number to swap inside your loop, otherwise your loop will just go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

I did some minor changes and it works.

- starting game may need to shuffle once. 
  call to `shuffle()` in `swap_puzzle()` (but don't shuffle it when printing)
- put `cin>> temp;` in the while loop so users can input till puzzle solved
- break the inner loop too(i added some vars for that)
- finally call to `check()` and break if true. thats means solved.

--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int grid[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0};

void shuffle()
{
    random_shuffle(&grid[0],&grid[9]);
}
void print_puzzle()
{
 //   shuffle();
    int a=grid[0];
    int b=grid[1];
    int c=grid[2];
    int d=grid[3];
    int e=grid[4];
    int f=grid[5];
    int g=grid[6];
    int h=grid[7];
    int i=grid[8];

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<a<<"  "<<b<<"  "<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<d<<"  "<<e<<"  "<<f<<endl;
    cout<<"     "<<g<<"  "<<h<<"  "<<i<<endl;
}

bool check()
{
    if (grid[0]==1&&grid[1]==2&&grid[2]==3&&grid[3]==4&&grid[4]==5&&grid[6]==7&&grid[7]==8&&grid[8]==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
else
   {
        return false;
   }

}


void swap_puzzle()
{
    shuffle();
    print_puzzle();

    int temp=0;
    bool swaped = false;
    while(1)
    {
        swaped = false;
        cout<<"Enter the number adjacent to '0' that you want to be swapped with '0'."<<endl;
        cin>> temp;
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            if(grid[i]==temp)
            {
                int pos_num=i;

                for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
                {

                    if(grid[j]==0)
                    {
                        int pos_0=j;
                        swap(grid[pos_num], grid[pos_0]);
                        swaped = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
                if(swaped) break;

        }
        print_puzzle();
        if(check()==true) break;
    }

}
int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout<<"The Rules:"<<endl;
    cout<<"There will be a shuffled 3x3 grid with numbers from 1-8, with one blank space denoted by '0'. You can swap '0' only with adjacent numbers. The goal of this game is to rearrange the numbers in the grid in ascending order."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The Shuffled Grid: "<<endl;
    swap_puzzle();
    return 0;
}
```